# How to use NSUserDefaults to store a container class

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to store a set of values under an NSUserDefaults key. I use a custom class to access an RSS feed and set the class's variables to match the info found in the feed. I then use another class to set the values under a NSUserDefaults key:

```
[infoStorageClass dataIsNew:self];
[infoStorageClass storeData:self];
```

The problem is that whenever I store my class I get this warning:

> [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
>       "TARSSInfo: 0x80eb6a0"
>   )' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

What's going on here? Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

In order to store an object of another type you first need to implement NSCoding protocol in the class of the object you want to store. Which means implement these methods and do decoding and encoding like this(a snippet of my own code of custom class BMDifficultyLevel):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
if (self = [super init]) {
    _difficultyLevel = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"difficulty"];
    _difficultyLevelType = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"type"];
}
return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
[encoder encodeObject:_difficultyLevel forKey:@"difficulty"];
[encoder encodeInteger:_difficultyLevelType forKey:@"type"];
}
```

then before storing your object you need to archive and then store like this:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
_defaultsDataWithLevelObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_difficultyLevel];
[defaults setObject:_defaultsDataWithLevelObject forKey:BMDifficultyLevelDefaultsKey];
```

where `_defaultsDataWithLevelObject` is an object of type NSData, which means eventually you store NSData object.

To retrieve your defaults you'll need to unarchive the object something like this:

```
    _defaultsDataWithLevelObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:BMDifficultyLevelDefaultsKey];
    _difficultyLevel = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:_defaultsDataWithLevelObject];
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for this answer. I think it might be easier for me just to store my values in an array, and then store that.

Comment: I stored all of the values (NSDate, 2 NSNumbers, and a CLLocation) in a NSDictionary, which I store in an NSMutable array, which I store in NSUserDefaults. I get the same error. :{

Answer (score 1):

You should make your custom class implement the `NSCoding` protocol and then archive your array of instances. This will give you an `NSData` instance that you can store into user defaults.